# How do I change the html element <li>'s color with a click via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to change the background color of UL 'li' on click?

EDIT
i can change li "a" but what about the entire **li**

this works:

```
 $(".clickableUL").click(function() {
           $(this).find("li a").addClass("active");

       });
```

but find("li") does nothing. I want the LI highlighted not just the text of the link.

Comment: Entire row?  Can you show us some of your HTML, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// javascript
$("li>a").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("clicked");
});

/* CSS */
li { background: blue; }
li.clicked { background: red; }
```

You could also use `display: block;` on the `<a>` to make it fill the `<li>` unless you want it to stay changed.

EDIT: d'oh! just realised you could also apply the click event directly to the `<li>` itself eg.

```
$("li").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

Comment: You might want to specify 'li > a' instead of plain 'a' for robustness.

Comment: ah yeah, i just thought of that but forgot the single level bit. Thanks :)

Comment: You forgot the >, or did you intend to omit that?

Comment: i changed it to "li a" and forgot adding a > but you're right it's better practice to make selectors as non-leaky as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the anchor's parent (assuming the parent is the <li> element.

```
$('a').click(function(evt) { 
   $(evt.target).parent().css('background-color', '#fff'); 
});
```